# Node.js express.js URL handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

So I'm currently practicing my node and express.js skills and it's all just a blur at the moment. So as a project I am trying to create a movie website like IMDB to develop my skills.

Now, on the home page of my website I want to have an input field where I enter a movie title. When submitted, I would like to send this search value to the server side.

On the server side (index.js) I have the following lines:

```
router.get('/search/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var name = req.params.id
    res.render('search', {
        name:name});
});
```

If I type the following in the url-bar of the browser:

```
http://localhost:4000/search/Magnolia
```

It shows me the ejs file I desire.

Now, my question is: **How can I transform my search value in the input (Magnolia in this case) to a URL (http://localhost:4000/search/Magnolia) that activates the router.get('/search/:id'...) in index.js?** + how can I immediatly load this search result page then?

Comment: *"It shows me the ejs file I desire"* <- doesn't that mean it's working? Your question is unclear

Comment: That's when I enter it in the URL window of the browser myself. I wonder how I can get that URL (http://localhost:4000/search/Magnolia) and fire the get request in index.js when I press the submit button next to the input value on my homepage.

Comment: Ah, the simplest approach is to use query parameters instead of path parameters, eg `<form action="/search" method="GET"><input type="search" name="id">...`. Otherwise, you're going to have to construct the URL via JavaScript and navigate to it

Comment: response before I reloaded: edited

Comment: interesting. Thanks, I'll check it out.